# some users are receiving notification in night from my android app

Tags: php, android

Some users are receiving notification in night from my android app
they are complaining that they are receiving notifications in late night and they are using internet data continuously full day...

The code is given below to send request to Google Cloud Messaging for push notification 1000 users in each iteration.

Please suggest where is the problem and what?

Thanks all in advance

```
<?

set_time_limit ( 100 ); 
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST["message"])) 
{ $regId = "";

$func = new DB_Functions();
$gcm = new GCM();
$message = $_POST["message"];
$message = array("newmsg" => $message);
$send_users = 0;
$limit = "";
$users = $func->getAllUsers($limit);
$no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($users);

$count = $no_of_users/1000;
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $registatoin_ids = array();
    $from = round($i,0)*1000;
    $limit = " limit ".$from.",1000";
    //$limit = " limit 0,2";
    $regids = $func->getAllUsers($limit);
    while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($regids))
    {
            array_push($registatoin_ids, $rs['gcm_`enter code here`regid']);
    }
    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
}

}

public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) 
{
// include config      
include_once './config.php';

// Set POST variables
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
    'data' => $message,
);

$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: notification can come at any time depends on availablity of data

Comment: But the users are saying they are using internet data continously

Comment: so what is the expected senario?

Comment: so what if there is 12h time difference?

Comment: i'm using php code in browser interface to send notifications the code to send request

Comment: Where can should i define the time to send push notification? without any time difference?